# Is is better to Stream.Write multiple times or concatenate string and Stream.Write once?

Tags: c#, .net, file, stream

I was just wondering, in terms of performance, which one is better (I'm using a StreamWriter in a FileStream):

1. Calling Stream.Write() multiple times:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    sw.Write(myList[i].ToString());
}
```

2. Concatenate all my strings into a single string and then calling Steam.Write() once:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    sb.Append(myList[i].ToString());
}
sw.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Thanks!

Comment: Better in what ways? Speed? Memory?   BTW: You may like this blog http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: You should be writingnonce

Comment: What kind of performance problems have you been noticing? It's easier for us to help you with your problem when we know what we're solving.

Comment: Why not try by yourself ?

Comment: in 2nd calling stringbuilder.Append() is also multiple times

Comment: If you want to know what's better in terms of performance, you have to _measure_. Frankly, it's unlikely that either is noticeable faster than the other, but only a measurement under real-world conditions will give you the information you really need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single answer to this. You can imagine that writing byte by byte, or character by character, usually causes overhead because each chunk of data travels through the layers of abstraction.

However you can also imagine that buffering as much as possible may not be optimal, ie. if you send data over a network stream, you would like the network to start transmitting data as soon as possible. And your application is busy buffering, so perhaps you're just moving the delay around instead of fixing anything.

In the case of a `FileStream` the operating system takes care of buffering, in normal circumstances you probably won't notice any difference between your two approaches.

Just write the data as is most fitting for your application, and if you find this is a bottleneck to your application, implement a buffered stream layer between the `StreamWriter` and the underlying `Stream` to counter the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, there's something else you should take on consideration before chosing one or another: if you write to the stream line by line, every line of the complete text is a chance for an I/O exception (specially when writing to disk); thus the more lines you're going to write, the more error-prone your code is. So, if there's no significant difference between your two approaches, either consider the second one, or have your code ready to recover if an exception ocurrs when writing half of the complete text.

Comment: Not every call to StreamWriter.WriteLine() causes an actual write operation, as StreamWriter caches the data before flushing them.

Answer (score 1):

I measured the duration using 3 different approaches:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly int NumLines = 100000;
    private static readonly int NumWords = 200;
    private static readonly string Word = "Oberbuergermeister";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        // approach 1: use string builder to cache all, then write
        stopWatch.Start();
        Approach1();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        stopWatch.Reset();

        // approach 2: write stuff line by line
        stopWatch.Start();
        Approach2();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString());
        stopWatch.Reset();

        // approach 3: write stuff string by string
        stopWatch.Start();
        Approach3();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.Elapsed.ToString());
    }

    private static void Approach1()
    {
        var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\1");

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < NumLines; cnt1++)
        {
            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < NumWords; cnt2++)
            {
                builder.Append(Word);
                builder.Append(";");
            }
            builder.AppendLine();
        }

        writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString());

        writer.Close();
    }

    private static void Approach2()
    {
        var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\2");

        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < NumLines; cnt1++)
        {
            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < NumWords; cnt2++)
            {
                builder.Append(Word);
                builder.Append(";");
            }
            writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
            builder.Clear();
        }

        writer.Close();
    }

    private static void Approach3()
    {
        var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\\temp\\3");

        for (int cnt1 = 0; cnt1 < NumLines; cnt1++)
        {
            for (int cnt2 = 0; cnt2 < NumWords; cnt2++)
            {
                writer.Write(Word);
                writer.Write(";");
            }
            writer.WriteLine();
        }

        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
00:00:02.8457431
00:00:01.5492287
00:00:01.4843888
```

Looks like it's best to call `StreamWriter.Write()` as often as possible and completely leave the caching to .NET. I haven't tried char by char, but line by line seems to be good enough anyway.